# JavaFX 2 and RCP

Tags: java, rcp, javafx-2

I am learning **JavaFX 2** now. I am just wondering can I use JavaFX 2 as a **web application** **AND** a **regular application**? That is as an admin, i can install the JavaFX 2 application on my local machine and use it as regular application to connect to the server for data access, and in the meantime my other customers will get the JavaFX 2 user interface via browser. By doing this way I only need to develop **ONE** application. My JavaFX 2 user interface can interact with my local files without special setup because it is installed locally.

does this sound right?

Comment: I only looked a bit at Java FX 2, but I think it's the whole point.  I  don't know how much extra code you would need to transform a desktop app to a web app, but I guess they tried to make it as small as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can and you should.

Every JavaFX application can be packed and run as jnlp or browser plugin web application.

If you install NetBeans 7.1 beta with JavaFX support, create a JavaFX project there and run Build then Netbeans will generate for you jar file, jnlp file and html file to show all 3 deployment options.

You can find more details here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/deployment/deploy_overview.htm#CEGHEAHD